# Is "Comment" a protected word in the Open API 3.0 spec or Swagger Editor?

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor, openapi

I'm currently working on an API spec using the Swagger Editor (v3.1.9) and the Open API 3 specification.

I'm getting some peculiar behavior specifically for a Schema component I have named `Comment`

```
Comment:
    description: "A comment on an asset or submission"
    allOf:
    - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Message"
    type: object
    properties:
      parent:
        oneOf:
        - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Asset"
        - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Submission"
```

In the UI, it renders as (with none of the inheritance from Message)

```
Comment   {
    description: A comment on an asset or submission
    parent     {
                oneOf ->    {
               }
             v {
             }
        }
}
```

However, if I rename it to anything else, say `Commentary` it will render fully (with inheritance from Message):

```
Commentary{
    description:    A comment on an asset or submission
    id  string($uuid)
    example: f1907c82-2c5f-4f60-8cd9-12647d411822
    author  User{...}
    body    string
            example: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    message_type    string
                example: DiscussionPost
    parent  {
            oneOf ->    Asset{...}
                        Submission{...}
            }
}
```

The only thing I can think of is that there is somehow a reserved word for Comment in either or both of the Open API spec or Swagger Editor. The main thing I want to know is if this is indeed a bug, or if I should be avoiding using this name (and if that's the case, if there are any others I should avoid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `Comment` is not a reserved word. Your schema is correct.

The schema rendering issue seems to have been a bug that is now fixed. Your schema is rendered correctly in the latest Swagger Editor.

[image]